# How to update custom image sizes?

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

I've added multiple custom image sizes using the `add_image_size` function. The problem here is when I need to update the proportions of these sizes, the changed sized won't apply.
My guess is that wordpress inserts those sizes in the database and it fails to update them upon code change.
How can I update the image size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this plugin you can choose which specific image sizes should be updated:
[AJAX Thumbnail Rebuild](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild/)

Or you can use [Simple Image Sizes](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-image-sizes/), too.

More infos on [wpbeginner](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-additional-image-sizes-in-wordpress/).

Comment: My problem is exactly with `AJAX Thumbnail Rebuild`. It uses the old image size.

Comment: Ok - maybe "Simple Image Sizes" or "Additional image sizes (zui)"

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be plugin - and as always: [There's a plugin for that](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/).

Comment: I prefer not to use a plugin in this case. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Any reason for this? You are only firing this when add_image_size change which should not be often. Only in developement. So in developement it deosnt really matter what kind fo plugins you have, you can just delete them once you go live.